# How to display bitmap in edittext using inputconnection

Tags: android

I am developing an emoji keyboard and want to print images on edittext of watsapp. I tried it using a spannable string but it prints only the text specified in the constructor. What do I have to do? My code is as follows:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(watsapp1[j]);
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
Log.i("",""+span);
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(" ");
ss.setSpan(span, 0,1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
//editT.setText(ss);
MainActivity.ic.commitText(ss, 1);
```

Comment: have you tried `HTML.fromHtml()`, which allows styling text with HTML tags?

Comment: yes but it didn't work.perhaps inputconnection is problem.

Comment: did you manage to solve it 
or could you find a way to retrieve the EditText from within the keyboard service